# Effective version of writing the following method

Tags: java

Is there an elegant and best approach to write the following method?

```
private void throwException(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof ClassA) {
        ClassA resp = (ClassA) obj;
        throw new CustomException(resp.getMessage(), resp.getCode());
    } else if (obj instanceof ClassB) {
        ClassB resp = (ClassB) obj;
        throw new CustomException(resp.getMessage(), resp.getCode());
    }
}
```

Note that ClassA and ClassB has the same exact properties. My point is that, I don't want to repeat the throw statement as much as possible.

Comment: Can you ensure that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` implement a common interface?

Comment: I can do that, but for this example it doesn't, just want to check if there are other ways to write the above without using common interface.

Comment: Did you mean `resp.getMessage()` and `resp.getCode`?

Comment: Why are you even down casting the `obj` if you are not using that? And if the `throw` doesn't use `resp` for it's constructor and also the `ClassA` & `ClassB` have same properties, I don't see any benefit of using `throw` in each `if` block. You can use `throw` outside of if statement without any fear.

Comment: Updated the code to use the defined "resp" object.

Answer (score 0):

Define a map like

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, ? extends RuntimeException>> handlers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

The `handlers` will contain a `Function` that you can use to map the `Object` passed to `throwException` to get an exception. The key of the map is a class and value is the function that will map an object of the *type* (class) of the key to an exception.

Populate the above map as

```
handlers.put(ClassA.class, (obj) -> new CustomException(((ClassA) obj).getMessage(), ((ClassA) obj).getCode));
handlers.put(ClassB.class, (obj) -> new CustomException(((ClassB) obj).getMessage(), ((ClassB) obj).getCode));
```

With this, `throwException` would look like,

```
private void throwException(Object obj) {
    Function<Object, ? extends RuntimeException> handler = handlers.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No handler found")); //Or use a default using orElseGet
    throw handler.apply(obj);
}
```

I agree that it moves the casting elsewhere to make the method look clean.

---

The key part is the line

```
.filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
```

We are checking if the *object* (passed to `throwException`) is of *type* returned by `entry.getKey` (the class of the map key). So, if you have inheritance hierarchy among the classes (`ClassA`, `ClassB`..), then you must populate the map in such an order so that the most generic ones (say like `Object.class`) comes *after* more specific ones.

A consequence of putting an entry into `handlers` with `Object.class` as the first entry would mean that the function (value) of `Object.class` will always be picked up for any object passed to it.

Comment: I am using Java 7, so I can't use Java 8 features.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Function<>`s to wrap the getters into a custom interface beforehand.

```
interface Wrapper {
   String getMessage();
   int getCode();
   <T> Function<T, Wrapper<T>> of(Function<T,String> getMsg, Function<T, Integer> getCde) {
       return object -> new Wrapper() {
           public String getMessage() { return getMsg.apply(object); }
           public int getCode() { return getCde.apply(object); }
       }
   }
}

class Thrower {
    Map<Class<?>, Supplier<Wrapper>> wrappers = new HashMap();
    static {
        wrappers.put(A.class, Wrapper.of(A.class, A::getMessage, A::getCode));
        wrappers.put(B.class, Wrapper.of(B.class, B::getMessage, B::getCode));
    }

    void throwException(Object o) {
        Wrapper wrapper = wrappers.get(o.getClass()).apply(o);
        throw new CustomException(wrapper.getMessage(), wrapper.getCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can kill two birds with one stone as this is a classical problem in the clean code design where you can choose to implement **Visitor Design Pattern** as a workaround to multiple If/else instanceof type of conditioning with a little bit of expansion to cover the problem of excessive throwing of new CustomExeption.

Here is what I can suggest you :

First it's better to change you design for ClassA and ClassB as:

```
abstract class ClassParent {
    // your fields

    public ClassParent (//your fields) {
           // initializing your fields
    }

    public abstract void accept(ClassVisitor cv); 
}

class ClassA extends ClassParent {
    public ClassA(//your fileds) {
        super(//your fileds);
    }

    /// other Implementation

    public void accept(ClassVisitor cv) {
        cv.visit(this);                           
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassParent {
    public ClassB(//your fileds) {
        super(//your fileds);
    }

    /// other Implementation

    public void accept(ClassVisitor cv) {
        cv.visit(this);                            
    }
}
```

Now define your vistors as  :

```
interface ClassVisitor {
    abstract void visit(ClassA classA);
    abstract void visit(ClassB classB);
}

class Visitor implements ClassVisitor {

    public void visit(ClassA classA) {
        classA.DoSomthing();
    }

    public void visit(ClassB classB) {
        classB.DoSomthing();
    }
}
```

Now it your ThrowException you can define :

```
private ClassVisitor visitor = new Visitor();
public void ThrowException(ClassParent classParent){
    classParent.accept(visitor);
    throw new CustomException(classParent.getMessage(), classParent.getCode);
}
```

> This way you achieve both a cleaner code, more maintainable with
>   higher readablity by avoiding duplicate codes at the same time.

Comment: There's already a comment on the question suggesting a common interface - which is pretty much the same as your `ClassParent` - and OP said he didn't want to do that. Also, the `obj` in your `ThrowException` is actually not declared, and it's not clear why the visitor should be called in the first place.

Comment: @daniu Perhaps the comments has been written while i was writing the answer that i didn't see it. that's not an unrelated answer and others might find it useful for themselves. anyway I really appreciate your minus :)

Comment: Well it helps to answer with code that actually compiles.

Comment: @daniu it seems you need more help then. to know how to compile this code raise a question I will help you.

Comment: Please feel free to enlighten me: https://ideone.com/9Wc1r0 - Seems to me the only way to compile this is to _change it_. Note that is _after_ I changed the erroneous `visitor.accept()` to `visitor.visit()` and some other minor adjustments.

Comment: @daniu yes, thanks ! you are right,  needed a minor change. check it on https://ideone.com/memGiM

Comment: Still, `ClassParent` defines neither `getMessage() ` nor `getCode() `. And once it does, your answer is correct - but I'm still missing the point of the visitor pattern for the problem at hand.

Comment: yes, that's right, i didn't go to the details too much. I just tried to represent the idea of avoiding the whole code duplicity and code smells, and about the visitor pattern, this is not I made up myself it's recommended in clean code principles to avoid instanceof as it is considered as code smell. for more info please take a look at http://letstalkaboutjava.blogspot.com/2016/10/do-you-really-need-instanceof.html

Comment: I'm aware of the pattern, but it's just not pertinent to the question. Having the common superclass is enough to cleanly create the Exception as OP wants.